# Windows: pwd with forward slashes, not back?

Tags: windows

Could anyone tell me how I can print the current working directory with *forward* slashes, not backslashes, from the Windows command line?

Thanks!

UPDATE: preferably I would like to do this without downloading any special utilities, but that may not be possible.

Answer (score 6):

You can do substitutions like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>echo %CD:\=/%
C:/WINDOWS/System32
```

Comment: +1 Nice, I didn't know you could do this.

Comment: I recommend typing `CMD /?` to a command prompt and reading the result. Do the same thing with other commands that get special mentions, but IF, SET, and FOR all have little gems hidden in their options.

Answer (score 2):

You could download [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and use sed.

> pwd | sed -e 's!\\!/!g'
>
> c:/Windows

Disclaimer, I don't have a windows PC in front of me to test this, but I have used sed on windows to solve similar problems.

Comment: thank you! ideally i'd like to do this without downloading anything - i'll hang on and see if anyone else suggests anything, otherwise will accept this.

Comment: The GNUWin32 utilities are pleasant to have around because they can reduce friction just enough for small things like this. They are light weight too, its not a huge commitment like an installation of Cygwin would be.